# iOS Send Push Notification to a device WITHOUT an application?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to send `Push Notification` to a device, **without** installing a specific app that would be receving it?

I know how to send a regular push notification, but I always need to install my app to receive them. I was wondering if there is any way to do it sending notifications directly to a device.
If so, what do I need? I do have a device `token` and other information, as I am using `MDM`.

Comment: This is not possible under iOS. You only can send push notifications to a specific (your own) app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not Apple this is not possible.

For all other developers, the user needs to allow you to send him notifications and for that you need to have the app installed.

Also, if he deletes the app, Apple will interpret this as you don't want to have any information from that app anymore - including notifications.

The only way is sending emails or sms ;)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me today, hence I did a search and found this. Fantastical 2 isn't stored on my second (non-SIM, wifi only) device, but I got a notification there only and not on the device with the app installed.